# Why doesn't C++ implicitly convert the LHS argument to a non-friend operator overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

Consider the following: ([Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/dx63o1ec1))

```cpp
class A {
private:
    int val;

public:
    inline A() : val(0) {}
    inline A(int x) : val(x) {}
    //inline bool operator<(const A& other) const {return val < other.val;}
    friend inline bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) {return lhs.val < rhs.val;}
};

int main(int, char**) {
    A a;
    //return 2 < a;
    return a < 2;
}
```

- This compiles.
- If the return statement is swapped for the commented one, it compiles.
- If the `operator<` line is swapped for the commented one, it compiles.
- If both of the above are swapped for their commented versions at once, it no longer compiles:

`error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'int' and 'A')`

Clearly, C++ is capable of performing implicit conversion (from `int` to `const A&`) on either side of the `<` when using the `friend` version of the operator. I would have expected the non-friend version to work the same, but it seems a value cannot be implicitly converted when it needs to end up as the "this" object in an operator overload.

I suppose if I defined a regular non-operator function instead of an operator, I wouldn't expect `(2).func(a)` to perform an implicit conversion either, so looking at it this way it makes sense, but it still seems weird that conversion isn't done in the case of an operator.

Does C++ disallow this form of implicit conversion because it considers it like a member function call? Or is there a different reason that's specific to operators? Does the standard make any comment on attempting to use a member operator in this way?

Comment: _"Does C++ disallow this form of implicit conversion because it considers it like a member function call?"_  Yes.  It **is** a member function, and it is being called.  You are attempting to call `2.operator<(a);`

Comment: Instead of posting code that works and explaining how to make it fail, show the code that fails.

Comment: The two `inline`s on the constructors aren't needed; members that are defined inside the class are implicitly inline.

Comment: Let's say your class had a non-`static` member function named `foo()`.  Would you expect the compiler to turn a call of `2.foo()` into `A(2).foo()`?   What would you expect to happen if another class (call it `B`) was also defined with a non-`static` member function named `foo()` and a constructor that accepts an `int` argument?    How would you expect that to work in different compilation units (source files) - where some have visibility of the definition of `A`, some have visibility of the definition of `B`, some have visibility of both, and some have visibility of neither?

Comment: It works that way because that's the way the rules are written. A member `operator<=>` will find the reversed candidate, proving it's possible and desirable. But (a) `operator<` is older and people didn't know and (b) can't be changed for fear of breaking code and  (c) the older relational operators are treated completely independently (a<b and a>b call independent functions), versus `operator<=>` which is designed with the relations in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler *first* selects a set of possible overloads, and *then* considers if some operands are convertible to the parameter types of any of those overloads.

The compiler does *not* do all possible convertions to find if any of those have suitable member functions (or operators).

Consider if `A` had a constructor

```
template<class T>
A(T);
```

Now the compiler would have to consider the member `bool operator<(const A& other)` for *any* type T. Not what we want.

Comment: If `A` had that constructor then surely the compiler would have to consider the operator for any type T anyway - if it was provided as the RHS or the friend definition was used.

Comment: The compiler selecting overloads first doesn't seem to preclude implicit conversions of the LHS. It's still deciding as part of that conversion step - for member functions, do not do an implicit conversion of the "this" object; for free functions, consider implicit conversions.